# SmartGit not showing uncommited changes in Log

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm having a problem with my SmartGit client (but probably it's related to  Git).

I have some uncommited changes, so I would assume that this would be shown as the first row in the graph (the Log view), but it doesn't. How do I get it back?

This screenshot shows what I'm looking for:

[image]

Also I'm working completely locally, so I don't have a remote repository (not sure if this makes any difference).

When running the command `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` in the Bash shell I don't get the **Uncommitted changes** row either. What figures?

Comment: What you are looking for will be implemented for SmartGit 18.2: https://smartgit.userecho.com/topics/27

Comment: @mstrap Fantastic, thanks! For some reason I thought this always was a feature in SmartGit, maybe it was just an illusion, as I come from a SourceTree background and find it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just an answer to the last part of your question, abut using `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.  You are wondering why you do not see a commit node for uncommitted changes.

`gitk` (a GUI that comes with Git) shows such a node; `git log --graph` does not.  It's up to each viewer to decide whether to pretend uncommitted changes are a commit node that can be shown, or whether they are just uncommitted changes and hence not a node.

The latter is more accurate from a technical point of view: uncommitted changes are *not* a commit!  However, showing them in the GUI may be more user-friendly.  So it's up to the GUI to decide whether to show them.

Note that from Git's point of view, there are actually *three* versions of each file available to you at all times.<sup>1</sup>  If you have a file named `README.md`, for instance, you actually have *three* `README.md` files:

- One `README.md` is stored in the current (`HEAD`) commit is there, read-only.  This copy can never be changed!  It is stored in a special, Git-only, compressed form.  Because it is stored in a commit, it is preserved for all time, or at least, as long as the commit continues to exist.

  If you have messed up the other two versions of `README.md`, you can recover the `HEAD` version using `git checkout HEAD README.md` on the command line.  This overwrites both of the other two copies.
- A second `README.md`, that will go into the *next* commit is there, read/write, stored in a hugely important, but normally almost entirely invisible (!), entity.  Git has three different names for this thing: it's called the *index*, or the *staging-area*, or the *cache*, depending on who's doing the calling.  All your current files are in the index, also in the special Git-only format, but here in the index, you can *change* them.

  Until you change this copy of the file, if you make a new commit, the `README.md` in the new commit will match the `README.md` that came out of the current commit.  This is true of all the other files as well.

  On the command line, you generally change this copy of the file using `git add README.md`.  That copies the work-tree version of the file (see the last bullet point) into the index.  If you decide you want the index copy to go back to the way it appears in the current commit, you can use `git reset HEAD README.md`.  This is very similar to `git checkout -- README.md` except that it *only* overwrites the index version from the `HEAD` version.
- Finally, there is the `README.md` file that you can actually open in an editor, view with a file viewer, and so on.  This file is the one in your *work-tree*.  It is in the ordinary, non-Git format, so that you can work with it.

  In some respects this is the file Git cares the least about.  Until you copy it into the index, it's just noise—Git hardly even looks at it.  The `git status` command will, however, compare the index version to the work-tree version, and tell you if they are different.

Note that what `git status` does is to run *two* `git diff`s: the first compares the `HEAD` commit to the index.  Whatever is different here is *staged for commit*.  The second `git diff` compares the index to the work-tree.  Whatever is different here is *not staged for commit*.

When a graphical viewer like gitk shows you a node for uncommitted changes, it is either conflating the index and work-tree, or ignoring one of these two.  Either way, what it is showing is not the truth!  Still, knowing that you *do* have uncommitted changes is valuable, whether those files are staged, unstaged, or both (e.g., maybe `README.md` is staged and some other file is unstaged).  It is nice to have a way to show this.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is both an overstatement and an understatement.  Since you can create new files, or remove existing files, sometimes the index and/or work-tree have versions that don't exist in `HEAD`, or vice versa.  That's where this is an overstatement: there might only be one or two versions of some file.  At the same time, you can extract *any* committed version of *any* file at *any time*, so this is an understatement—but the `HEAD` commit version is particularly important as it is what `git status` will use when comparing to the index.  Last, there's yet another special case when working on a merge that has conflicts: in this case, the index itself holds (up to) three versions of the conflicted files, so that you wind up with even more simultaneously-available versions of each file.